# Display dialog after choose from list

Tags: applescript

I have been playing with applescript for a while and i am making a text version of pokemon. I have a choose from list and a if statement to start a display dialog. when you press Run it should say "You cannot run from a trainer battle" but the display dialog never opens. I can't see what is wrong. I have been searching google but can't find a solution

here is the code

```
set userStarter to "undefined"
set starterHP to "undefined"
set starterLV to 5
set starters to {"Charmander", "Bulbasor", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"}
set userName to "undefined"

on battle(traner)
display dialog traner & " wants to battle!" buttons {"Next"}
set battleMenu to {"Attack", "Bag", "Run"}
set temp to {choose from list battleMenu}
if temp is "Run" then
    display dialog "You cannot run from a trainer battle" buttons {"Ok"}
end if

end battle


display dialog "Welcome to text based Pokemon!" buttons {"Play", "Quit"}
if the button returned of the result is "Play" then
set temp to display dialog "What is your name?" default answer "Ash" buttons {"Submit"}
set userName to text returned of temp
set userStarter to {choose from list starters}

display dialog "Oak: Okay " & userName & " here is your " & userStarter buttons {"Next"}
display dialog "Gary: Hey, lets battle!" buttons {"Battle"}
battle("Gary")


end if
```

here is the log

```
tell application "AppleScript Editor"
display dialog "Welcome to text based Pokemon!" buttons {"Play", "Quit"}
    --> {button returned:"Play"}
display dialog "What is your name?" default answer "Ash" buttons {"Submit"}
    --> {text returned:"Ash", button returned:"Submit"}
choose from list {"Charmander", "Bulbasor", "Squirtle", "Pikachu"}
    --> {"Pikachu"}
display dialog "Oak: Okay Ash here is your Pikachu" buttons {"Next"}
    --> {button returned:"Next"}
display dialog "Gary: Hey, lets battle!" buttons {"Battle"}
    --> {button returned:"Battle"}
display dialog "Gary wants to battle!" buttons {"Next"}
    --> {button returned:"Next"}
choose from list {"Attack", "Bag", "Run"}
    --> {"Run"}
end tell
```

Comment: Aw, I was messing with applescript and was planning to do text pokemon too :D I only found this question by searching for "applescript buttons"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem.

This line is wrong, remove the { }: (otherwise you are pushing the return of the *choose from list* into a list, the return is already a list)

```
set temp to {choose from list battleMenu}
```

Then choose from lists returns a list so you have to check so:

```
if temp is {"Run"} then
    display dialog "You cannot run from a trainer battle" buttons {"Ok"}
end if
```

(But if you want to show up the dialog if you press bag you should replace "Run" with "Bag")

The complete code is then:

```
set battleMenu to {"Attack", "Bag", "Run"}
set temp to choose from list battleMenu
if temp is {"Run"} then
    display dialog "You cannot run from a trainer battle" buttons {"Ok"}
end if
```

Comment: Oh sorry made a mistake in my question it should be run not bag. thanks for the help